# Left cosets and right cosets

Tags: group-theory

In *Topics in Algebra* Chapter 2 Section 5 Problem 5, Herstein asks to show that the left and right cosets of a subgroup are in one-one correspondence.  If the the group is finite, or abelian, it's trivial, but what about in general?  Somehow I'm not seeing it.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try to find a bijection from the set of left cosets to the set of right cosets. There aren't many "natural" possibilities for it.

Answer (score 4):

Left cosets are the multiplicate inverse of right cosets, i.e., we have
$xH=yH$ if and only if $Hx^{-1}=Hy^{-1}$, where $H$ denotes the subgroup of $G$. This gives a bijection.

Comment: Well, images under the inverse-taking map at any rate.

Comment: @Dietrich if i define map as f(ah)=ha .what is problem in that ?